# How to stop dock icons from shaking when receiving a notification?

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, notification, dock

I recently upgraded to 22.04LTS, and ever since the upgrade, my Dock-Icons have started to wiggle when there is an unread notification. Apparently, not all 22.04 users are experiencing this behavior, so I am unsure what could cause it. Does anyone have an idea how to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

try disabling enable-animations with dconf-editor or run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

If you use cinnamon instead of gnome:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```