# How to disable icon wiggle animation in the dock?

Tags: unity, icons, dock, animations

Apparently there is this animation that let's your applications icon wiggle when there is an urgent notification. How do I disable this wiggle?

Comment: Try this: `gsettngs set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock workspace-agnostic-urgent-windows false`. Let me know the result: if it works, I will add an answer.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425787/how-to-stop-dock-icons-from-shaking-when-receiving-a-notification) has worked for me:

try disabling enable-animations with dconf-editor or run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

If you use cinnamon instead of gnome:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Comment: Tried it on Ubuntu 22.04, doesn't work.

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me on 22.04. I wish they'd stop trying to make the UI look like Crap OS.

Comment: same here, i like a screen where i can concentrate not some jiggling icon to distract me (same for all this JavaScript on the web)  I have gone into setting, disabled animation there and disable animation and urgent in dconf.  I will try Kubuntu (KDE) and see if thats better.  but when you log in, you can change your display to like xfe or something.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 23.10

Comment: 22.04 doesn't work